# According to this equation for glycolysis, what is reduced and where do the electrons go?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, redox

I know that the glucose is oxidized into pyruvate but I don't understand what is reduced or where the electrons go....

Equation:
$\ce{Glucose + 2 ADP + 2 NAD^+ -> 2 Pyruvate + 2 ATP + 2 NADH}$

Comment: Look up the 2 reactions ADP -> ATP and NAD+ -> NADH.

Comment: This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. It would be nice if you could share what the abbreviations stand for to make this question self-sustained.

Answer (score 1):

NAD+ accepts a hydride ion (proton + 2 electrons) and is reduced to NADH.

Comment: Yomen, would you mind elaborating a little bit? This seems really really comment-like to me and it might to other people.

Comment: I think its okay, it answers exactly the question how it was asked. The question itself is none of the brilliant ones though.

Answer (score -1):

I think the question "where do the electrons go?" is excellent, and if answered correctly can excite otherwise disinterested students into chemistry. This is because the only way to properly answer the question is to get into the mechanistic details which are at the heart of chemistry. And it's not that hard, given a quality image to point out the specific "electron pair". I've included one of many [images that can be found on the web](https://employees.csbsju.edu/hjakubowski/classes/ch331/oxphos/OP_8C2_Anerobic_Coup_Ox_ATP_Syn.html) for the mechanism of Glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate (G3P) Dehydrogenase below. The precise answer to the question is that the "electrons come from the bond attaching the hydrogen directly to the carbonyl carbon of G3P.  This corresponds to the same hydrogen in the open chain form of glucose, and that, in turn can spark further questions about that. Unfortunately, despite the central importance of this step, many (I would say most) educators would have trouble answering with this precision. No wonder chemistry gets a bad reputation.

[image]